# How to get if a zip code is in australia or not in android?

Tags: java, android

In my new project I am providing user an edittext where he has to put a zip code, i have to check if this provided zip code is valid for Australia or Not. I am getting so much suggesions, but I need the easiest and simplest one. Moreover it would be the best If I could find a webservice from where I could check this.

Comment: If it's in Australia, it's not a Zip code, it's a postcode. "Zip code" is a US-specific term, which isn't used elsewhere in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't live in Australia but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_Australia) says:

> Australian Postcodes are four digits

Why don't you just test your zipcode against a Regular Expression that describes this (simple) pattern?

I suggest you to read the [allocation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_Australia#Allocation) for the zipcodes and see whether there are contiguous or if there are non valid zipcodes inside a given range...

Now if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I guess you can use geocoding APIs the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) or [Yahoo! Placefinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/). The implementation could be simple: send the postcode (I suppose you could be allowed to send only this information) and check in the response whether the country is Australia or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an api you can use : [Sensis](http://developers.sensis.com.au/)

Comment: Do you know of any API where I can check if the phone number entered by the user is valid or not or any thing closely related to that?

Comment: I know [Whitepages](http://developer.whitepages.com/) does for sure in the US not very about Australia.
You might check on this api though : 
[Reverse Australia](http://www.reverseaustralia.com/developer/)